# AWS Kinesis for web services

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

One of my client is having an existing application which reads data from a third party service, write in to my database. Later this data is used for creating webservices to my android app.

Now the entire code is migrated to AWS and my client wants a better service to do this. So on investigation, I found the AWS service "Kinesis" can be used for data streaming. Unfortunately this not available in free tier to try out. If someone with experience in AWS can tell me whether I can use "Kinesis"  for this web service purpose ?

Thanks and regards,
Tismon Varghese.

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to achieve?

Comment: this is my requirement ----- One of my client is having an existing application which reads data from a third party service, write in to my database. Later this data is used for creating webservices to my android app. ---- My question; is Kinesis is the best aws service to achieve this ? If not; is there any other better services in AWS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinesis is a service that is able to get events in one end and let you process these events on the other end, and be a buffer in the middle to store these events for a period of time.

Yes, you can ingest events from any source into Kinesis (as long as they are smaller than 1MB - see more limits here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/service-sizes-and-limits.html). You can also read the events on the other side and put them into your Database (Redshift, RDS or your DB on EC2).

You can have multiple options to read these events. It can be completely automatic if you use Kinesis Firehose to write into Redshift. It can be serverless using AWS Lambda that is triggered when you have new events in your kinesis stream. And it can also be done on your servers with your own code using open source library: KCL (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/developing-consumers-with-kcl.html).

Kinesis is extremely low cost and you can try it out for couple of dollars and even less for a couple of days. There are many options to optimize its usage if you are starting to use it heavily, but you first need to start out to get into the real-time events-processing mindset.